# how to read a csv file from a url?

Tags: c#, csv

Im trying to create a web service which gets to a URL e.g. `www.domain.co.uk/prices.csv` and then reads the csv file. Is this possible and how? Ideally without downloading the csv file?

Comment: Without downloading the CSV file?  How do you expect to read it?  Or do you just mean read a portion of it without having to download the whole thing first.

Comment: Do you want to do that client side or server side?

Comment: Downloading doesn't mean you have to save the file to disk if that is what you think. That being said, you can't read the file without downloading it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use:

```
public string GetCSV(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string results = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    return results;
}
```

And then to split it:

```
public static void SplitCSV()
{
    List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
    string fileList = getCSV("http://www.google.com");
    string[] tempStr;

    tempStr = fileList.Split(',');

    foreach (string item in tempStr)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
        {
            splitted.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Though there are plenty of CSV parsers out there and i would advise against rolling your own. [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) is a good one.

Comment: If you're reading the whole file into a string anyway and do not need the additional flexibility of `WebRequest` you can just use `WebClient.DownloadString`.

Comment: If you use `VisualBasic.IO.TextFieldParser` you can use something that's already built into .NET by just adding a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. After that use this instead of the stream reader.

`using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(response.GetResponseStream()))`

Answer (score 2):

In your Web Service you could use the WebClient class to download the file, something like this ( I have not put any exception handling, not any using or Close/Dispose calls, just wanted to give the idea you can use and refine/improve... )

```
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.domain.co.uk/prices.csv");
```

then you can do anything you like with it once the file content is available in the execution flow of your service.

if you have to return it to the client as return value of the web service call you can either return a `DataSet` or any other data structure you prefer.

Comment: hmmmm so if i wanted to put the csv into a datatable, would i do datatable table =  webClient

Answer (score 1):

[Sebastien Lorion's CSV Reader](https://github.com/Sjord/CsvReader) has a constructor that takes a Stream.

If you decided to use this, your example would become:

```
void GetCSVFromRemoteUrl(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true))
    {
        int fieldCount = csvReader.FieldCount;
        string[] headers = csvReader.GetFieldHeaders();

        while (csvReader.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            //Do work with CSV file data here
        }
    }

}
```

The [ever popular FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1_ReadStream.htm) also allows you to read directly from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) has an example that uses streams. Using a stream allows you to parse the document without storing it all in memory